# Vsftpd is not working properly

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, centos-7, vsftpd

OS：CentOS 7.6 64bit

### problem

The FTP service is not working properly. Repeatedly log in when connecting. Unable to authenticate user.

Information is provided below. If you know how to solve this problem, please help me, thank you.

[image]

### Configuration code：

```
sudo useradd ftpuser -d /product/ftpfile -s /sbin/nologin

sudo chown -R ftpuser.ftpuser ./ftpfile/
sudo passwd ftpuser
cd /etc/vsftpd
sudo vim chroot_list
sudo vim /etc/selinux/config
sudo setsebool -P ftp_home_dir 1
sudo systemctl start vsftpd.service
```

### error info

`Jan 05 12:24:49 iZwz9fclplrmrf3jr9s6fuZ vsftpd[32313]: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan 05 12:24:49 iZwz9fclplrmrf3jr9s6fuZ vsftpd[32313]: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ftp ruser=anonymous rhost=42.48.210.139`

[image: status]

### vsftpd.conf

```
local_root=/product/ftpfile 

anon_root=/product/ftpfile
use_localtime=YES

anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

local_umask=022

dirmessage_enable=YES

xferlog_enable=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES

xferlog_std_format=YES

ftpd_banner=Welcome to mmall FTP Server

chroot_local_user=NO

chroot_list_enable=YES

chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list

listen=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES

pasv_min_port=61001
pasv_max_port=62000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your config:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
```

From the error message:

```
authentication failure; ... ruser=anonymous ...
```

To summarize: you try to login as anonymous user but access for anonymous is explicitly disabled. No wonder it fails.

Comment: I changed the “anonymous_enable” to “yes”, but still prompted the login to fail.

Comment: @ThomasLee: Make sure that the server was restarted so that the option takes effect. If it still not works please provide new log files.

Comment: I opened ports 20 and 61001~62000, added "pasv_enable=YES", and it worked. :)

Comment: @ThomasLee: in this case the new problem was a different one: the login now worked after enabling anonymous access but firewall settings blocked transfer of data and directory listings.